# What does late spring mean?

Tags: meaning

I'm learning English through the Merriam Webster's Vocabulary Builder now.
And here's a question.

"As a result of the ocean, Canada's Maritime Provinces-New Brunswick, Nova Scotia, and Prince Edward Island-have a late spring but a mild winter."

I understand a mild weather condition in winter as a result of the ocean, but what does a late spring have to do with it? I can't grasp the meaning. Please help me out. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

A *late spring* refers to the arrival of the season. In some countries it stops snowing and being cold anytime between late February and the end of March (**early spring**). In other climates the warmer weather arrives in May or even June (**late spring**).

Comment: Thank you for your comment. It helps me a lot. I appreciate it.

Answer (score 0):

I think late spring means that the warming comes late - for instance, in the second half of April or in May. Instead, the early spring would mean that the warming comes in March.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I really appreciate it. It helped me a lot in a better way to understand English.